# What are the names of JOIN parts

Tags: sql, language-lawyer

If I have an expression, parts of the expression typically have names so that we can talk about them, e.g. in

```
A - B
```

- `A` is called the *subtrahend*
- `B` is called the *minuend*
- the result is called the *difference*.

So how do I talk correctly about a JOIN in SQL? For instance

```
A JOIN B ON A.id = B.a
```

Within this join, what are the names of the components?

- `A`: ?
- `B`: ?
- `A JOIN B`:
- `A.id = B.a`: *join condition* ?
- `A JOIN B ON A.id = B.a`: ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [BNF grammar for the SQL-99 standard](http://savage.net.au/SQL/sql-99.bnf.html), my *interpretation* is this:

- `A`: *`<table reference>`*
- `B`: *`<table reference>`*
- `A JOIN B`: this would be a *`<qualified join>`* but it is missing a *`<join specification>`*
- `A.id = B.a`: *`<search condition>`* which is a *`<boolean value expression>`*
- `A JOIN B ON A.id = B.a`: *`<qualified join>`*

A *`<join condition>`* is specified as *`ON <search condition>`*

And here is the relevant part of the [BNF grammar for SQL-2003](http://savage.net.au/SQL/sql-2003-2.bnf.html#joined%20table) (which is a bit more recent, although I believe it should be almost identical).

Comment: I thought of that, too, but these are the BNF terms, which rather describe types. For instance, in the BNF for a subtraction, A and B would be `value expression`, not subtrahend and minuend.

Comment: I don't have access to the actual finalized standards document (as it's not free of charge), but looking at the the draft for the SQL2011 standard ([available in a archive-file](http://www.wiscorp.com/sql20nn.zip)) the syntax terms from the grammar are what is used in the standard. While I get what you are looking for and the distinction from the grammar terms I I don't think you'll find any other normative names. This is probably as good as it gets, and I believe these terms would certainly be correct to use in communication.